# Timer does not want to stop by .prototype.stop

Tags: javascript, timer, prototype

Why timer `clock.start();` does not want to stop by using function `clock.stop();`.

I'm using typical function `clearInterval` in prototype `stop` to stop function `start`. Bur after calling `clock.stop();` the timer in function `clock.start();` does not stop.

I can not understand why...

```
function Clock(options) {
  this._template = options.template;
}

Clock.prototype._render = function() {
  var date = new Date();

  var hours = date.getHours();
  if (hours < 10) hours = '0' + hours;

  var min = date.getMinutes();
  if (min < 10) min = '0' + min;

  var sec = date.getSeconds();
  if (sec < 10) sec = '0' + sec;

  var output = this._template.replace('h', hours).replace('m', min).replace('s', sec);

  console.log(output);
};

Clock.prototype.start = function() {
  this._render();
  var self = this;
  this._timer = setInterval(function() {
    self._render();
  }, 1000);
};

Clock.prototype.stop = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(this._timer);
    console.log('Stop!'); // message is displayed, but timer in **this._timer** does not stop...
  }, 5000);
};

var clock = new Clock({
      template: 'h:m:s'
    });
clock.start();
clock.stop();
```

Comment: Problematic line `clearInterval(this._timer);`. `this` is not what you think

Comment: @elclanrs Yes, you're right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve a problem in a function `clock.stop();`, it is necessary to apply a closure similarly applied to the function clock.start();

So we need to put the this._timer in the local variable and  accessing directly to they by using the clouser method.

in the `Clock.prototype.start` we did clouser

```
  this._render();
  var self = this;
```

So we need to make the same in `Clock.prototype.stop` such

```
var sef = this._timer;
```

and use local variable sef in the timer function.

So simple, but I understand it only now.

Thanks to @elclanrs for a aiming :)